# Fill input on jQuery event doesn't make the placeholder of the input disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder

I update the value of an input box through a jQuery change event of a drop-down, like this:

```
$('#category_id').on('change', function () {
    $('#title').val('(' + $(this).find('option:selected').text().replace(/^[-]+/, '') + ') -> (' + $('#eshop_category_id option:selected').text().replace(/^[-]+/, '') + ')');
})
```

This works fine, however, when it happens, the placeholder text of #title input box remains there, looking like a mess...

I didn't know I need to take care of the placeholder in such cases. And I don't know how to take care of it, now that I learnt the hard way that I need to take care of it.

Can someone tell me the proper way to deal with this? TIA

Comment: `$('#title').prop("placeholder" , "Any Thing Here").val(....`

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason!!! Although it'd make sense to work...

Comment: @FayeD. you need to add your html code

Comment: My bad... The placeholder isn't added through the placeholder property... It's defined like this: `<label class="" id="title-prompt-text" for="title">Add title</label>` so I had to do it like this: `$('#title-prompt-text').text('');`

Comment: Per your deleted post, consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/taoscv0r/

Comment: @Twisty I deleted it because they closed it... Since you offered so willingly your help, could you please go a bit further by making the fiddle work like this: The duration of the timer each time will be either 60 or 120 or 180 seconds depending on the quiz. Can you point me to the correct place in your fiddle where this is defined, so that I can set it appropriately? Also, there should be only two colors: #00f for 100%, and #f00 for 0%. Any moment in between those should be a gradient of the two. Even when recovering with a delay, the starting color should be the gradient of that percentage.

Comment: @FayeD. if a post is closed, there is a reason. You can edit the post, addressing the reason, and it can be re-opened. So keep that in mind in the future. I can do this, yet it does not help you learn. Try forking my fiddle and see if you can make the adjustments yourself. If you run into an issue, post a new question.

Comment: @Twisty I'm in such a hurry to deliver this task that I literally don't have the time to study the documentation of JQ Progressbar, that's the reason I can't figure it right now. Plus, I'm in front of the computer 10hrs straight already... But I promise I'll study it meticulously if you help me with it. :)

Comment: Per my other post, the message was "Closed. This question needs to be more focused"... Though it had a code snippet (my work on the matter so far), so it showed initiative, prior study etc... But yet, someone decided it was not focused... Of course it couldn't be very much focused, the whole post was made because I can't figure out what makes my code not work sometimes and I can't figure out why... Anyway...

Comment: @FayeD. take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/taoscv0r/80/

Comment: @FayeD.Updated as widget if you care: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/taoscv0r/172/

Comment: @FayeD. last update: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/taoscv0r/186/

Comment: @Twisty I think I'll stick to my solution. My approach (without using the JQ progressbar) runs smooth (not in 1s steps) and I when I add an initial delay, it "resumes" the countdown from that point, using the correct color gradient that corresponds to that position in the progressbar. Yours works a little differently. Plus, I think I found the problem that caused my progressbar to not appear some times... I was using `$(window).on('load', function () {` to initialize it, but it seems that for some unknow reason that event doesn't always fire... It misses one time out of 10-15 on average...

Comment: So I changed it to `$(document).ready(function() {` and I've done more than 50 tests so far, and it always appears... Strange that the `.on('load')` event doesn't always fire, but it it what it is and I spent already so much time on this... Maybe some caching plugin doesn't load a side-resource making the event not fire at times... Or maybe it's something else, but `.ready` seems to overcome this, so that's good enough for the situation. Thanks a million for your effort and time! You're such a kind gentleman!